# Bash: difference between cat and echo

Tags: bash

This is `file.txt` (without an end-of-line for the last line):

```
foo:bar:baz:qux:quux
one:two:tree:four:five:six:seven
alpha:beta:gamma:delta:epsilon:zeta:eta:teta:iota:kappa:lambda:mu
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

#### File *read.sh*

```
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
done < file.txt
```

This is what I tried in the terminal:

```
./read.sh
```

Output:

```
foo:bar:baz:qux:quux
one:two:tree:four:five:six:seven
alpha:beta:gamma:delta:epsilon:zeta:eta:teta:iota:kappa:lambda:mu
```

Why doesn't `read.sh` show the last *end of line* like `cat file.txt` does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because there is no end of line in file.txt, if you:

```
$ od -c file.txt
0000000   f   o   o   :   b   a   r   :   b   a   z   :   q   u   x   :
0000020   q   u   u   x  \n   o   n   e   :   t   w   o   :   t   r   e
0000040   e   :   f   o   u   r   :   f   i   v   e   :   s   i   x   :
0000060   s   e   v   e   n  \n   a   l   p   h   a   :   b   e   t   a
0000100   :   g   a   m   m   a   :   d   e   l   t   a   :   e   p   s
0000120   i   l   o   n   :   z   e   t   a   :   e   t   a   :   t   e
0000140   t   a   :   i   o   t   a   :   k   a   p   p   a   :   l   a
0000160   m   b   d   a   :   m   u  \n   t   h   e       q   u   i   c
0000200   k       b   r   o   w   n       f   o   x       j   u   m   p
0000220   s       o   v   e   r       t   h   e       l   a   z   y    
0000240   d   o   g
```

There are no `\n` at the end of the file.

`echo` on the other other hand will always add a new line when you echo a message if there isn't one.

Comment: `wc -l` is a good way to confirm this. So is `od -ta`, to show where newline characters are present.

Comment: @Joe wc -l is not quite right to detect this: it shows 3 if there is no training \n - `od -c`  is a good way to confirm if there is a \n - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers are right, there is simply no newline character in the end of your `file.txt`.

Most text editors will end a file with a newline automatically, even `nano` does that. But your file was generated by a script, right?
To reproduce this behavior all you have to do is:

```
echo -n 'hello world' >> file.txt
```

`-n` flag tells echo not to output the trailing newline.

Also, if you want your `read` code to work, you can use this:

```
while read -r line
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < file.txt
[[ -n $line ]] && printf '%s' "$line"
```

This is going to work because actually `read` will place the last line into the variable, but it also will return *false*, thus breaking the while loop.

Comment: Some editors remove it instead. For instance, the one in the [Arduino IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino_IDE) (at least later versions). And even all empty lines at the end. A workaround for code is to add some inconsequential line, like a comment line, at the end.

Comment: @PeterMortensen if an editor is removing a newline at the end of files, then it's a bug, report it.

Answer (score 4):

Your input file doesn't end in a newline.

`cat file` simply copies the file contents to standard output. It operates by characters, not lines, so it doesn't care if the file ends in a newline or not. But if it doesn't end in a newline, it won't add one to the output.

`read -r line` will read a line into the variable. It will only report success if the line ends in a newline. If the last line of the input doesn't end in newline, it reports an error, as if EOF had been reached. So the loop terminates when it tries to read the last line, instead of returning that line. That's why the script never displays the line beginning with `the quick brown fox`.

In general, Unix text-file programs are only defined to work on text files that end in newline. Their treatment of the last line if it doesn't have a newline is not usually specified.

Comment: I've never actually looked at the contents of the variable when `read` returned an error, so I didn't realize the distinction. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `file.txt` does not contain a newline at the end of the last line. Hence `cat` does not show it.

Note that `read.sh` does not display the last line at all... in `read.sh`, `read` is waiting for a complete line of input, and since the last line is not terminated by a newline, so it is not actually read.